# Making A Gradient Between 2 Colors in XNA

Tags: c#, colors, xna, textures, gradient

I am making a GUI library for Monogame/XNA, and I decided that instead of using textures for the buttons, I would use a struct to hold information on gradients and colors in the gradient. Then I could pass a width and a height into the struct and it would calculate a gradient from the two colors stored in it and pass back a texture with the correct dimensions and the applied gradient.

What I was wondering was the most efficient way to go about calculating a two color gradient (with transparency). I have seen a bunch of answers to this, including shaders, HSL conversions, and applying a color to a white->black gradient. None of them were very detailed or supplied code examples. I would assume the most efficient way to do this would be drawing to a render target with shaders, but I have almost no experience in shaders. And since it is a library (.dll), I wouldn't even begin to know how to load content like shaders and to draw with them.

This is kind of the effect that I am going for:
[Image](http://i44.tinypic.com/a2pycx.png)

Also, I am trying to make it more customizable as to allow for different directions for the gradients, i.e.

```
public enum GradientStyle
{
    NONE = 0,
            RADIAL,
            HORIZONTAL,
            VERTICAL,
            BLEND
};
```

This is by no means required. I just want to know how to make a simple gradient for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple linear gradient is easy:  draw a quadrilateral polygon with two of its vertices set to one color and two of its vertices set to a second color.  The gouraud shading will interpolate between the two colors to create a gradient.

Anything beyond that is going to get a lot more complicated.  XNA, and DirectX more generally, are APIs built for handling textures and polygons.  Drawing highly customizable gradients is an operation more suited to direct pixel manipulation.

This is why you're hearing recommendations to use shaders.  Pixel shaders allow you to directly set the color of each pixel that is drawn, making them ideal for creating gradients.  You don't necessarily need render targets; you can set a custom shader through `SpriteBatch` prior to rendering your GUI primitives and draw the gradient real-time, which avoids the need to allocate additional video memory.

If you want to learn how to write HLSL shaders in XNA, you might take a look at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/773/what-are-some-good-resources-for-learning-hlsl) from the GameDev Stack Exchange.  Shawn Hargreaves also has [a short article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) on the basics of writing shaders specifically for use with `SpriteBatch`.  The shader files are just XNA content files, included in your content project; you load them using `Content.Load<T>()`, just like any other content file.

Once you've mastered the basics of HLSL shaders, you can create pixel shaders that implement the algorithms for drawing common types of gradients, then apply a different shader in `SpriteBatch.Begin()` depending on the settings for the GUI component that is being drawn.

Note:  The above applies to Microsoft XNA 4.0.  I believe MonoGame has a means of converting HLSL shaders into GLSL shaders for use on OpenGL platforms, but I have no experience with it.  I would recommend learning the basics on MS XNA first, since that's what most of the tutorials you'll find online will assume that you're using.

Comment: I like the idea of using a quad and setting each vertex to a different color, then using gouraud shading to make the gradient. The thing is, how would I go about making the quad stay on screen as 2D, like I was drawing it with a spritebatch? From what I can remember, the quads are locked in 3D space and therefore wont stay in the same position onscreen as soon as the camera moves.

Comment: Remember, `SpriteBatch` isn't actually doing anything special; it's just drawing 3D polygons under the hood.  That means you can write your own code that does exactly what `SpriteBatch` is doing.  Exactly how to do so is beyond the scope of this answer, but basically you need to draw the polygons using an _orthogonal projection_--there's plenty of information on how to do so on the Internet.  Still, I question whether it's really worth it; your options for customization are going to be extremely limited, and you can get a very similar effect using simple textures.

Comment: You will have to excuse me, as I am very new to 3D graphics, but you will have to explain or point towards an explanation of the differences between the different projection types. I tried looking up orthographic projections, and they look like they can be used to render 3D primitives to the 2D screen, but I'm still confused on how to go about implementing the features.

Comment: Basically, you need to create an orthographic projection matrix using one of the [static methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.createorthographicoffcenter.aspx) on the `Matrix` class, and then set that as the projection matrix on whatever `Effect` you're using to draw your primitives.  Get a handle on how to draw basic primitives in 3D space using `BasicEffect`, then try to go from there by replacing the view and projection matrices.

Comment: Ah, I found [this tutorial](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xnagamestudioexpress/thread/475d53a9-a014-4244-a514-e132ecec7695/), which really helped. I now have what I need to do this. Thanks for the help.